# How many Gs would you experience at the sun's core

Tags: magic, gravity, astronomy

Thinking of the inside of the sun, how many Gs can I subject someone to in a magic field of altered gravity before the atoms within the field start to undergo fusion? It's not like anything within the field isn't already being crushed into dust, but I don't want to literally turn the field into a massive improv. fusion generator and have to deal with the leakage of excess heat.

So how many Gs of force would you experience at the metaphorical heart of the sun? And as a point of reference, how many at the heart of a gas giant?

Comment: You need to elaborate what your magical field actually does. Matter won't ignite into a star simple because gravity is affecting it, you need pressure for that.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - do you want to know when fusion starts relative to gravity or how much gravity there are in stars and gas giants' cores - which is related but not necessarily as helpful --?

Answer (score 5):

At the center of a star or gas giant, it's not so much gravity working on you directly that you need to worry about, it's gravity working on everything that makes up the star/gas giant.  IE, not gravity, but pressure.

The center of the Sun is estimated to be around [265 billion bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_core).  Earth's atmosphere at sea level is a slight bit over 1 bar (1.01325 bar, to be precise).  So anything in the center of the Sun would be subjected to ~261 billion times the pressure that it does at the Earth's surface.

You mention that you "don't want to literally turn the field into a massive improv fusion generator and have to deal with the leakage of excess heat", but the center of the Sun quite literally *is* a massive fusion generator.  That excess heat is handled quite readily by being radiated out as sunlight.

As for gas giants, Jupiter's core is estimated somewhere north of [200 GPa](http://www.universetoday.com/47966/jupiters-core/), or a bit under 2 million times Earth's atmosphere at sea level.  Not quite enough for fusion (which is why Jupiter is still a gas giant and not a star), but enough to compress hydrogen to the point where it becomes [metallic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen).

So, either way, you're well past "dust" and into the realm of "hot, hyper-compressed monatomic fluid".

Comment: Actually, (only) an ICAO Standard Atmosphere at Earth ground level is 1.01325 bar (1013.25 hPa); it's also defined to be exactly +15.0°C, which it rarely is in practice. Compare [ICAO Standard Atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Atmosphere#ICAO_Standard_Atmosphere).

Comment: Okay, sure, but at the scale we're talking about, the actual pressure variation of the atmosphere in any given place is entirely insignificant, so the ICAO Standard Atmosphere works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You're asking the wrong question.

The number of Gs at the sun's core is simple:  Zero.

Just like the gravity at the center of any other body with spherical symmetry.

The only way you'll have any gravity at the center of a body is if the body is asymmetric.  That doesn't happen to any great degree even in planets (the pressures at work will equalize it if it starts out unbalanced), let alone stars.

What you care about in the center of the sun is temperature and pressure.

Comment: The OP was aware of this, as stated in [the first revision](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/revisions/64258/1).

Comment: @HDE226868 Ok, but I didn't see that version of the question.

Comment: Indeed, I think one could define the 'center' of an asymmetric body as the point where gravity is zero.  Comet /Churyumov–Gerasimenko, anyone?

Comment: @jamesqf I would define the "center" of an irregular object based on the center of volume.  Besides, consider an object that's a hemisphere of lead and a hemisphere of rock.  Few would disagree about the location of the center and it wouldn't be the center of mass.